3D structures, involving a significant number of objects.(In THREE React Fiber )
I'm developing a 3D application where users create geometry (planes). As the number of planes increases, performance suffers due to high draw calls. How can I effectively optimize draw calls and plane rendering for a smoother user experience?
Here's what I've done so far:
Took input.
Created basic functions to generate buffer geometry using four points, five points, and six points.
Utilized those functions to create a member, such as an L or T-shaped geometry, using the given coordinates. For example, for a rectangle-shaped member, I used a four-point plane to create its six sides.
Then, I used a for loop and other calculations to determine the position of those members and draw them accordingly.
However, I've encountered an issue where the application is lagging significantly, sometimes dropping to 1 or 2 frames per second, which is not acceptable.
I want to boost performance, and the best solution I've found is to utilize InstancedBufferGeometry. Could you please help me with it?
Or maybe there's a simpler way to do what I'm trying to do?

Or maybe there's a simpler way to do what I'm trying to do? I didn’t see what you were trying to do  basically. And what help you expect my Friend… help with instancing? Did you try implement these steps: https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/advanced/scaling-performance and https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/advanced/pitfalls

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
